# Rails 4 - scope with has_one instead of attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following two models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :archive, :dependent => :destroy

class Archive < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
```

`Archive` holds `person_id`.

I need to have a scope `Person.with_archive`. Since `Person` has no db column of `archive_id`, the only solution I found is:

```
def self.has_archive
  res = Array.new
  self.all.each do |i|
    res << i if !i.archive.nil?
  end
  res
end
```

The problem is that I get an Array instead of a relationship, which limits me to chain other scopes.

Any nice and clean solution for that?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
scope :with_archive, -> { joins(:archive) }
```

This should return only the Persons with an archive, because `joins` uses an `INNER JOIN` statement.

Comment: Can the `joins` be replaced with `includes`?

Comment: @Pavan No, that's not the same thing: `joins(:archive)` means "where an archive exists" whereas `includes(:archive)` means "load archive if it exists".